# Reading Nested XML Structure to get values

Tags: java

I am trying to fetch values from nested xml structure. I have used multiple for loops for it , but it is giving me following exception:
"java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method org.w3c.dom.Node.getTextContent() of a null object returned from org.w3c.dom.NodeList.item(int)"

XML:

```xml
    <Testing>
        <Keys>A11</Keys>
        <Details>
            <Data>
                <FName>K</FName>
                <LName>S</LName>
            </Data>
            <Data>
                <FName>U</FName>
                <LName>C</LName>
            </Data>
        </Details>
    </Testing>
```

Code:

```java
        NodeList details= doc.getElementsByTagName("Details");
        if(details != null && details.getLength() > 0)
        {
          for(int j = 0; j < details.getLength(); j++)
          {
            Element serie = (Element) details.item(j);
            NodeList data = serie.getElementsByTagName("Data");
            for(int z = 0; z < data.getLength(); z++)
            {
              NodeList LineItem = data.item(z).getChildNodes();
              if (LineItem != null && LineItem.getLength() > 0) 
              {
                for (int i = 0; i < LineItem.getLength(); i++)
                {
                  System.out.println("Data"); 
                  System.out.println("FName: " 
                    + doc.getElementsByTagName("FName").item(i).getTextContent());
                  System.out.println("LName: " 
                    + doc.getElementsByTagName("LName").item(i).getTextContent());
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Expected Output:

```
    Data
    FName:K
    LName:S
    Data
    FName:U
    LName:C
```

Answer (score 1):

**The first problem:**

```
NodeList LineItem = data.item(z).getChildNodes();
if (LineItem != null && LineItem.getLength() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < LineItem.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Data");
        System.out.println("FName: " + doc.getElementsByTagName("FName").item(i).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("LName: " + doc.getElementsByTagName("LName").item(i).getTextContent());
    }
}
```

You've already picked the `<Data>` nodes, So you don't need to have `getAllChildNodes` and again iterate over them declaring them as elements. Most importantly, you're pulling `"FName"` and `"Lname"` from `doc`, not the `LineItem` and the corresponding item number is iterating.

However, You can simply do the following Instead of the block I've mentioned above:

```
Node node = data.item(k);
if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element element = (Element) node;
    System.out.println("Data");
    System.out.println("FName: " + element.getElementsByTagName("FName").item(0).getTextContent());
    System.out.println("LName: " + element.getElementsByTagName("LName").item(0).getTextContent());
}
```

That will do your job.

**The second problem:**

Your `xml` file has a wrong tag `<Fname>` and `in the second``. Which will, anyways lead to the` NullPointerException`. So please correct the tags to` `and``

Comment: Hi devReddit, Fname was typo mistake. Tags in both the <Data> are same. I have corrected the input xml in my post

Comment: What is data , is that <Data> from xml and what is K, is it the for loop iterator?

Comment: exactly @Kaushik, data is the `<Data> elements from xml, data is the `NodeList` acheived from `serie.getElementsByTagName("Data");` and while iterating over this nodeList, `k` is used as the loop iterator

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to pull the FName and LName from `doc` and not from `LineItem`.

Comment: Hi Andres, I tried fetching from LineItem but now its just returning back lables without values. I did the following: Element series = (Element)LineItem.item(i); then for printing series.getElementsByTagName("FName"), is this correct?